# videojs in WeChat doesn't work for rtmp

Tags: rtmp, video.js, wechat

I want to play rtmp in WeChat and it can play on my PC browser, but in WeChat browser on Android, it returns:

> "No compatible source was found for this video"

But on iPhone it just shows an infinite loading screen.

```
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js/video-js.swf";
  </script>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://www.pageresource.com/wallpapers/wallpaper/bleach-ichigo-mugetsu-here-size-original_215405.jpg"
      data-setup="{}">
     <source src="rtmp://hsn.mpl.miisolutions.net/hsn-live01/mp4:420p500kB31" type='rtmp/mp4'>
    <!--source src="rtmp://219.232.161.204/livestream/mtzysunq" type='rtmp/mp4' / -->
    <!--<track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>--><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <!--<track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>--><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
  </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

No browser supports rtmp without flash. videojs uses a flash fallback for rtmp (video-js.swf). Mobile devices do not support flash, hence no flash fall back, hence no video. You need to use a format other than rtmp. Like mp4, hls or dash.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can I use mp4 or hls to live stream my camera video?

Comment: Without knowing what camera you have, I don't know how to answer. There are many threads here about live streaming, look at those first. If they don't answer your questions, open a new question.